# converting json string to texteditor

Tags: json

i am a real noob. The thing is, i dont know where to turn. we, as in myself and my thesis partner are trying to build (theoreticly) a platform which has an own search engine directed only at the databases of wikipedia. Now when you download articles or an article, using the wikipedias api you get a json formatted string, now the question is how do i convert that json code string into just text?
 like a plain simple english?
and if you have any suggestions on search algorithms for the search engine that would also be helpfull.

(note) if you can give me an explanation otherwise just give directions on keywords to search for

Comment: No info about any thing like the language or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use a function to convert that json to object and then take the property that is of interest to you.

pseudo code:

```
function getTextFromwikiArticleJson(json){
  var realobject = JSON.decode(json);
  return realobject.content.body; 
}
```

Comment: thank you, it was as i suspected, shame, wanted to se how it would have looked like. taken som programming courses so i have an understanding of it, but almost cannot write a single line of code, to bad!

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just (one of) the format(s) used to transfer data over internet. It then needs to be processed (i.e. parsed) in order to extract the information you want.

A wikipedia API call might give you much more information than you actually want (so called meta-data), such as creation date, authors, etc.

You are probably interested in the text of the article, so you need to access the corresponding entry in the JSON.

Try pasting the JSON in an online parser, such as https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser.
Also, read about JSON here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Most programming languages have functions to parse JSON data (often via external libraries, such as gson for Java, for example)

Comment: yes i saw that the meta data was also retrieved from the string. thank you, forgotten that the word was parser, so i tried google json converter, no luck there!